# Ошибка "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python-3.x

Что нужно сделать, чтобы начать работать с Google Assistant?
Работаю по этому мануалу https://webcheerz.com/install-google-assistant-in-windows-10/

на этом этапе

```
/ py m pip install google-assistant-sdk[samples]/
```

заменил эту строку на

```
py -m pip install google-assistant-sdk[samples]
```

результат:

```
...
        orig_path.sort(key=position_in_sys_path)
    AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\User01\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-n3z63wfr\googleapis-common-protos\
```

что нужно на этом этапе сделать?

Comment: ос - windows 10

Comment: скриншот https://yadi.sk/i/3ZAW1AEN3L4Pht

Comment: посмотрите, что-то простое же.

Comment: приветствую! кто-то здесь поможет решить задачку?

Comment: Проблема наверняка в том, что вы используете руководство, написанное каким-то идиотом, который не замечает очевидных ошибок в своем тексте. Используйте руководство от Google: https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/prototype/getting-started-pi-python/run-sample

Comment: может быть, проблема не снимается, как работать по этой методике? developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/prototype/…

Comment: установлены win10 и python3.

Comment: дошел до https://yadi.sk/i/hacHX0we3LAANL

Comment: дальше встал, что делать?